# why my react js button click event not working

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning React.js and confused on the below code:

```
btnClick(){
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={alert("button clicked!")} >Click me</button>
        </div>
    )
}
render(){
    return(
        <div> 
            {this.btnClick()}
        </div>
    )
}
```

the alert only get prompted after refreshing every time but not when clicking. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write:

```
<button onClick={() => alert("button clicked!")} >Click me</button>
```

And

```
{this.btnClick}
```

or

```
{() => this.btnClick()}
```

Comment: The second code won't work. The right would be `{this.btnClick()}`. You need to call the function. Fiddle [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/62v264zqzr)

Answer (score 0):

`{this.btnClick()}` is fine but you need to change the alert function to `onClick={() => alert("button clicked!")}`